# Is it correct to model a specialized table using a foreign key whose referencing attributes are not also forming its primary key?

Tags: database-design, inheritance

In the process of designing a database model, I would like to implement a *Class Table Inheritance* pattern in a way that does not seem common at first. I would like to know if it is a correct implementation of this pattern.

### Simplified context

The database represents various piping components that can be connected to each other via their inputs and outputs.

Examples of components:

- A pipe is a simple component with an input and an output;
- A selector is component that contains an internal mechanism to connect its single input to one of its many outputs.

In order to represent the component connections with simplicity, I created a first set of specialization/generalization with a superclass `componentinput` and the subclasses `pipe_input`, `selector_input`, etc. as well as another set of specialization/generalization with a superclass `componentoutput` and the subclasses `pipe_output`, `selector_output`, etc. This allows me to easily represent the connections with the table `componentoutput_connection` that references `componentoutput` and `componentinput`.

Please note that the specializations are both *complete* and *disjoint*. The necessary triggers and functions will be implemented to enforce the completeness and disjointness.

**Graphic representation of the model**

Here is a partial graphic representation of the model (made with MySQL Workbench 6.3) with only the selector and its corresponding input and output specializations:

[image: model]

**SQL commands of the model**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selector` (
  `selector_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`selector_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `componentinput` (
  `componentinput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`componentinput_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selector_input` (
  `selector_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `componentinput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`selector_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_selector_input_selector_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`selector_id`)
    REFERENCES `selector` (`selector_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_selector_input_feedcomponentinput_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`componentinput_id`)
    REFERENCES `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `componentoutput` (
  `componentoutput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`componentoutput_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `selector_output` (
  `selector_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `output_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `componentoutput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`selector_id`, `output_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_selector_output_selector_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`selector_id`)
    REFERENCES `selector` (`selector_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_selector_output_feedcomponentoutput_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`componentoutput_id`)
    REFERENCES `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `componentoutput_connection` (
  `componentoutput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `componentinput_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`componentoutput_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_feedcomponentoutput_connection_feedcomponentoutput_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`componentoutput_id`)
    REFERENCES `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_feedcomponentoutput_connection_feedcomponentinput_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`componentinput_id`)
    REFERENCES `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**SQL commands of a data set example**

```
-- There are 4 selectors.
INSERT INTO `selector` (`selector_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `selector` (`selector_id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `selector` (`selector_id`) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO `selector` (`selector_id`) VALUES (4);

-- Each of the 4 selectors have their input.
INSERT INTO `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO `componentinput` (`componentinput_id`) VALUES (4);

INSERT INTO `selector_input` (`selector_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO `selector_input` (`selector_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO `selector_input` (`selector_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO `selector_input` (`selector_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (4, 4);

-- Each of the 4 selectors have 3 outputs.
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (9);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (10);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (11);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput` (`componentoutput_id`) VALUES (12);

INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (1, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (2, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (2, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (2, 3, 6);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (3, 1, 7);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (3, 2, 8);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (3, 3, 9);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (4, 1, 10);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (4, 2, 11);
INSERT INTO `selector_output` (`selector_id`, `output_id`, `componentoutput_id`) VALUES (4, 3, 12);

-- Each of the 3 outputs of the first selector is connected to the input of selector 2, 3 and 4.
INSERT INTO `componentoutput_connection` (`componentoutput_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput_connection` (`componentoutput_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO `componentoutput_connection` (`componentoutput_id`, `componentinput_id`) VALUES (3, 4);
```

The common way to design a subclass is to make the attributes that compose the foreign key to the superclass its primary key. However, I did not do this on my design since the subclasses were already dependent on their respective component. Indeed, `selector_output` represent *an-output-of-a-selector* and as such, it has a primary key composed of `selector`’ primary key, which prevents me to reuse `componentoutput`’ primary key as `selector_output`’ primary key.

So, is it correct to model a specialized table using a foreign key—referencing the generalized table—whose referencing attributes are not also forming its primary key?

Comment: Simple designs are always better. I would say to you - what is the purpose of the design? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese I also prefer the simplest design possible that fits the requirements. The purpose of this design is to track the current and past connections of the components.

Comment: you got some example data? That might help.

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese: I have edited the question by adding data examples.